# Visual movement of the caret in WPF text editing elements

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

For a bidirectional project, the client want all text editing elements to have visual movement - when the flow direction is right to left (with a right to left language) and the caret of the editing element is on a (long) number, hitting right arrow on the keyboard should move the caret one digit to the right.

Currently, the movement is logical, i.e. hitting right arrow moves the caret one digit to the left.

How do I set visual movement in WPF (an option that is available in MS word, if it matters)?